# Installing Gmail Material Design APK

Tags: applications, signature-error

I have the APK File to the pre-release of Gmail Material Design. I went to Google Play Store and uninstalled my current, up-to-date Gmail package. When I install the material design APK, it tells me that an app with the same signature already exists. What app? I just uninstalled it,  it should just install, no? After all, I even went to ES File Explorer >> App >> Gmail >> Uninstall. I am not rooted and I use Blu Studio 6.0 HD.

Comment: Did you try to reboot your device after uninstalling Gmail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NOTE: The Gmail 5.0 apk is currently causing a lot of issues and force closes on numerous devices, and without root I doubt this will work. **Proceed at your own risk.**  As a non-root user I would wait until Google roll out the update.

The signature already existing means that you already have something with the same package installed: Gmail! Gmail may well be a system app on your device and is not being unistalled properly. The actual /system/gmail.apk may remain despite it seemingly uninstalling, especially on a non-rooted device. The conflict is happening as you are trying to install an app you already have.

The easiest way around this is to uninstall Gmail. [root](/questions/tagged/root) users can simply uninstall the application, and install Gmail 5.0. You ***could*** disable your existing Gmail application `Settings > Applications > Gmail > Disable` and try to install the apk, but as I said at the start there is a very high chance you will get endless force closes.

One of the workarounds on [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/app-gmail-5-0-t2912373/page3)  for ROOT ONLY:

I am showing this less as a guide, and more as an illustration of the issues at the moment.

- Rename old gmail.apk Pushed/renamed new Gmail.apk Change permissions
- Then clicked on the app in Root Explorer and installed it --- this
  time it installs successfully.
- Then I deleted all app cache and app data.
- Changed the r.build.type=userdebug
- Saved.